# How to properly add the checked users in a certain group?

Tags: django, django-views

views

I have a checkbox to check the users in order to add them in a group.Here If the checked user is already in the group then it fails now with this code but I want proceed(if checked users are already in) and add the remaining user to the group and leave the already added user as it is.

It throws this error if the checked users are in the group already

> UNIQUE constraint failed: user_registration_user_groups.user_id,
>   user_registration_user_groups.group_id

```
def assign_users_to_group(request, pk):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            users = request.POST.getlist('users')
            for user in users:
                if user in group.user_set.all():
                    pass
                group.user_set.add(user)
            messages.success(request, 'users added to this group')
            return redirect('user_groups:view_group_detail', group.pk)
```

**UPDATE** with Nafees Anwar answer

```
def assign_users_to_group(request, pk):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        users = request.POST.getlist('users')
        for user in users:
            try:
                group.user_set.add(user)
            except IntegrityError as e:
                if user not in group.user_set.all():
                    raise e
        messages.success(request, '{} user added to this group')
        return redirect('user_groups:view_group_detail', group.pk)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def assign_users_to_group(request, pk):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        users = request.POST.getlist('users')
        for user in users:
            if not user.groups.filter(name=group.name).exists():
                group.user_set.add(user)
        messages.success(request, 'users added to this group')
        return redirect('user_groups:view_group_detail', group.pk)
```

Comment: `str` has no attribute groups

Comment: Use User's object in if condition.

Comment: You are probably fetching list of string users from request.POST

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore if it raises error and user exists.

```
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError

try:
    group.user_set.add(user)
except IntegrityError as e:
    if user not in group.user_set.all():
        raise e
```

Comment: May be you missed something can you add code after change in question?